# $f$ is analytic and bounded by $1$ in the unit disc with $|f(α)| \neq 0$ for some $α \ll 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is analytic and bounded by $1$ in the unit disc with $|f(α)|$ different of $0$  some $α \ll 1$. Show that there exists a function $g$, analytic and bounded by $1$ in the unit disc, with $|g'(α)|>|f'(α)|$.

Comment: what do you mean by $\alpha \ll 1?$

Answer (score 1):

For $a\in \mathbb D,$ define the well known automorphism of $\mathbb D$

$$\varphi_a(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}.$$

Then $\varphi_a'(0) = |a|^2-1,$ $\varphi_a'(a) = 1/(|a|^2-1).$

Now take $f$ to be your function, so that $f(0)=a\ne 0.$ If we consider

$$\varphi_{f(a)}\circ f \circ \varphi_{a},$$

we have a map that takes $0$ to $0.$ By the Schwarz Lemma, the derivative of this function at $0$ has modulus $\le 1.$ Use the chain rule and $f(a)\ne 0$ to see this implies

$$|f'(a)| \le \frac{1-|f(a)|^2}{1-|a|^2} < \frac{1}{1-|a|^2}.$$

Since $|\varphi_a'(a)| = 1/(1-|a|^2),$ we have the desired solution.