# How to find $ f'(a)?$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some doubt in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3109223/557708)

Here is the outline of the given answer

For $a\in \mathbb D,$ define the well known automorphism of $\mathbb D$

$$\varphi_a(z)=\frac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}.$$

Then $\varphi_a'(0) = |a|^2-1,$ $\varphi_a'(a) = 1/(|a|^2-1).$

Now take $f$ to be your function, so that $f(0)=a\ne 0.$ If we consider

$$\varphi_{f(a)}\circ f \circ \varphi_{a},$$

we have a map that takes $0$ to $0.$ By the Schwarz Lemma, the derivative of this function at $0$ has modulus $\le 1.$ Use the chain rule and $f(a)\ne 0$ to see this implies

$$|f'(a)| \le \frac{1-|f(a)|^2}{1-|a|^2} < \frac{1}{1-|a|^2}.$$

Since $|\varphi_a'(a)| = 1/(1-|a|^2),$ we have the desired solution.

**My  doubt** : How  to find $ f'(a)?$

**My attempt** :take $h(z)=\varphi_{f(a)}\circ f \circ \varphi_{a},$  . here h is satisfied schwarz  lemma  so $h(0)=0$ and  $h(z) \le |z|$

$h(z)=\varphi_{f(a)}\circ f \circ \varphi_{a}\le |z|\implies |f ( \varphi_{a} )|\le|\varphi_{f(a)}^{-1}(z) |$

therefore $$|f ( \varphi_{a} )| \le \frac{f(z)- f(a)}{ 1- f(a)f(z)}$$

After that im  not able to proceed further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that answer I didn't find $f'(a)$ exactly. But I showed $|f'(a)|<|\varphi_a'(a)|,$ and that was enough to answer the question there.

I'm not sure what you are doing in your attempt. I am not using $|\varphi_{f(a)}\circ f \circ \varphi_{a}(z)|\le |z|.$ I am using $|(\varphi_{f(a)}\circ f \circ \varphi_{a})'(0)| \le 1.$

Comment: thanks  u got  it @zhw  i think  it can also   solved by  taking $h(z)=\varphi_{f(a)}\circ f(z)$  instead of $ \varphi_{f(a)}\circ f \circ \varphi_{a}$

Comment: But your $h(z)$ doesn't send $0$ to $0.$

Comment: ohh!! u r right @zhw